# Seeing that $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is a field

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

I have some basic question with polynomials appreciate if someone could explain me this.

Following is additional and multiplication tables and it is say that this **is a field**. Have no idea why say it is field.

Please explain me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know what a field is?

Comment: @Rhys- I know very less. The definitions are very difficult to understand me.

Comment: See the answers below to understand what a field is.  Even if the notations are a bit complicated for you to understand, you should get the hang of what the answerers explain to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just note that, for multiplication, every non-zero element on the first column has, on its line, a $1$, which means it has a inverse to the right...
Now, for every element on the first row, which contains nonzero elements, it has a 1 on its column, which means it is left-invertible.

Thus, it is a field since every nonzero element is invertible.

Comment: You made a good point!

Comment: And I just entered Math Stack Exchange! :P Begginer's luck I guess.

Comment: Don't worry about this.  Everyone has the first time.  Nobody can go far beyond the "StackExchange" habitants, or people who go on that site for very long time (Know: experience!)  Good job posting the great answer!

Comment: Last line must be: "...since every **nonzero** element is invertible"...just nitpicking, and welcome! +1

Comment: In order to become a field, the two scenarios (row wise and column wise) should be there or having 1 is enough?

Comment: @NewDeveloper if it is commutative, then only one scenario is enough.

Comment: @DonAntonio i edited that. Thanks and thanks! :)

Comment: That should be enough to make this response a better answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks @OhMyGod. Also the buddies who gave their options :)

Comment: Wow... I got a silver badge before realizing what badges are '-'

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is a ring with unity and $f\in R[x]$ a polynomial, then $R[x]/\langle f\rangle$ is always at least a ring. To be a field, it needs a unity (check) and each nonzero element must have a multiplicative inverse (check).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer of Hagen von Eitzen above (I credit his work), it is a well-known result if $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is Euclidean domain. And (given a irreducible polynomial (irreducible in F[x]), say $r(x)$ in $F[x]$) if $D=F[x]/<r(x)>$, then $D$ is a field. As a example, $R[x]/<x^2+1>$ is field (can you see which field)? Now, for proving the final result, all that we need to prove is (over $F_2$), $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible. As $x^2+x+1$ is a degree $2$ polynomial, we merely need to show $x^2+x+1$ has (in $F_2$) no roots. Thus...