# Prime field intuition

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, intuition

Can anybody give some intuition behind a prime field?

So the prime field of $K$ is the field that results when we intersect every subfield of $K$. But if this has characteristic $p$ for some prime, why does any multiple of $p$ in the field equal zero?

To an extent I see that every subfield contains $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but that vision of mine is not very clear and I do not feel comfortable working with it. I do not really even know what it means that every subfield contains $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Would anybody be able to provide some intuition behind this? Or perhaps some resources that would provide some underpinning theory that would make this fact seem obvious?

Comment: Think about the characteristic $0$ case instead, maybe you have more intuition there. Can you, for instance, see why every subfield of $\Bbb C$ (like $\Bbb R$, or $\Bbb Q(i)$, or more exotic subfields) contains $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Not really to be honest. For example it contains the subfield $2\mathbb{Z}$, but it's not even completely clear to me that that subfield "contains" $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is $2\Bbb Z$ a field, though?

Comment: Oh wow that's embarrassing. It is not. Okay so I think I see that any subfield will then contain $\mathbb{Q}$. But how do I generalise this partial understand to fields of characteristic more than 0?

Comment: Think about _why_ $\Bbb Q$ must be in any subfield of $\Bbb C$. Any subfield must contain $1$, and you must be able to use the standard field operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication and division by non-zero). Can you, just from $1$ and all the field operations, construct any rational number?

Comment: Hmm yes you can. And no subfield has characteristic more than 0, so we can make any rational in any subfield. So then I can make any integer less than p in any field that has characteristic p, because once I make p by adding the unit to itself p times it will revert to 0. That is a very helpful idea!

Answer (score 4):

I think it is very helpful to understand the "minimal" example of such a field in characteristic $p>0$, namely for $p=2$ the field $\Bbb F_4$ with $4$ elements. It contains the prime field $\Bbb Z/2$ in a very natural way, but is itself of course quite different from $\Bbb Z/4$, which has zero divisors and thus is not a field. Fortunately this site has many good explanations on how to understand $\Bbb F_4$:

[Can you construct a field with 4 elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42143/can-you-construct-a-field-with-4-elements)

[Addition and Multiplication in $F_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777107/addition-and-multiplication-in-f-4)

[Seeing that $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377314/seeing-that-bbb-f-2x-x2x1-is-a-field?rq=1)

[Why $F_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ has $4$ elements and what are those?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997022/why-f-2x-x2x1-has-4-elements-and-what-are-those)

[What is the difference between $Z/(4)$ and the field $F4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213462/what-is-the-difference-between-z-4-and-the-field-f4?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Why does $(a+1)(a+1)=a$ within a field $F_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274993/why-does-a1a1-a-within-a-field-f-4)

Comment: Oh nice idea. How can I think of $\mathbb{F}_4$ though? It is not a cartesian product of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and it is not $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How can you think of $\Bbb F_4$ though? Exactly for this question I have added the links for you. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should think about the prime field $P$ of $K$ this way: it is the smallest subset of $K$ which is also a field, whose operations are inherited from $K$. Clearly, any subfield must contain the element $0$ and the element $1$. Unlike with rings, there are no subfields with an identity element different from $1$ because all elements are invertible. $1$ belongs to $P$, so $1+1,1+1+1,1+1+1+1$, etc. all belong to $P$. In the case of a field $K$ with non-zero characteristic, $1,2,3,4,\cdots ,p-1$ all belong to $P$. Also, $P$ must be closed under multiplication and have an inverse for every non-zero element. In the case of a field with characteristic $p$ this doesn't make us include any new elements in $P$, since every element in $\{ 1,2,3, \cdots ,p-1\}$ has an inverse, also in $\{ 1,2,3, \cdots ,p-1\}$. But if $\text{char}(K)=0$, then all fractions ($a/b,b\neq 0$) also belong to $P$. Nothing else is needed, so those are all possible prime fields; either $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.
The definition of the smallest field is quite abstract and not constructive, and I think that the constructive way provides more intuition.